# Is there API methods to convert BigDecimal(seconds) to years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds?

Tags: java, time, bigdecimal

The title of the question includes all the details.

If I have `BigDecimal seconds = new BigDecimal("32365423.56");`
Is there API methods that convert this to:
n years, n months, n days, n hours, n minutes, n seconds.

If time is ambiguous in seconds, then assume in seconds these values: (I'm not confined to these values)

```
   BigDecimal year = new BigDecimal("31556908.8");
   BigDecimal month = new BigDecimal("2629739.52");
   BigDecimal day = new BigDecimal("86400");
   BigDecimal hour = new BigDecimal("3600");
   BigDecimal minute = new BigDecimal("60");
```

Comment: Unlikely. The question is ambiguous, since a month does not have a fixed size. A precise answer would depend not just on the number of seconds, but when the interval begins (or equivalently, when it ends).

Comment: @chepner I add some detail to the question, I don't know if that can facilitate. Any way thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenient methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal seconds = new BigDecimal("32365423.56");
        Duration duration = Duration.ofNanos(seconds.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1_000_000_000)).longValue());
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedDuration = String.format("%d days %d hours %d minutes %d seconds", duration.toDays(),
                duration.toHours() % 24, duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedDuration = String.format("%d days %d hours %d minutes %d seconds", duration.toDaysPart(),
                duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT8990H23M43.56S
374 days 14 hours 23 minutes 43 seconds
374 days 14 hours 23 minutes 43 seconds
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the java.util.Date class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29 together with the java.util.Calendar class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

You would is it like that:

```
long l = Math.round(seconds.doubleValue());
Date d = new Date(l);
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(d);
int sec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
...
```

Comment: You are assuming that the number of seconds represents a specific point in time, not an interval.

Comment: well, i think i misunderstood the question